# Why my phone is sending some other phone number as my caller ID and for SMS?

Tags: lineageos, 7.1-nougat

I've been using LineageOS 14.1 on ZUK Z1 for quite a while now. One problem I am facing is, sometimes my phone sends text messages from some other number which I don't even know. This also happens to the calls, my phone number is replaced with someone else's number.

Couple of days ago I did a fresh install of LineageOS 15.1 hoping this will fix the issue with my phone, but that had some other problems attached with it. I wasn't able to connect my phone to PC through USB cable, lots of apps were crashing making phone unusable. I had to go back to LineageOS 14.1 but this is not the main question. I wanted to ask what can be the issue which is causing the phone to use someone else's phone number as my phone number while calling or for the SMS purposes?

My friends pointed this thing lots of times and also referred the numbers through which my SMS or call was delivered. After calling those numbers I got to know they are people within my area at the time of my messages being delivered from their numbers. This problem is not on some specific region, I travel a lot and this happens no matter where I am which makes it clear it is not fault in my area's network coverage.

I tried searching for problem like this but I wasn't able to find any single, that's why I am posting this.

There is also another problem which I forgot to mention earlier, my phone restarts on its own sometimes.

Any help would be appreciated!

By the way Lineageos 14.1 is basically Android 7.1 and Lineageos 15.1 is Android 8.1.